# PHP foreach of multidimensional array

Tags: php, foreach

I have an array and it has two arrays inside of it...I am able to access what I want for the first row by doing this...

```
print_r( $_SESSION['shopcart']['cart']['qty']);
```

How would I write that in a foreach?

Thanks,
J

Comment: What is the entire array?

Comment: I cant really post the entire array as it has delicate information.

Comment: False data is fine; we just need to know the structure.

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($_SESSION['shopcart']['cart']['qty'] as $value) {
    echo $value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you would do something like this:

to dump the array: `$_SESSION['shopcart']['cart']`

```
foreach($_SESSION['shopcart']['cart'] as $key=>$value){
    echo $key." => ".$value."<br/>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to iterate through multiple dimensions, you can nest foreach as follows:

```
foreach($_SESSION['shopcart'] as $cart) {
    foreach ($cart as $qty) {
        // do something
    }
}
```

Though I'd need a little more information about the array structure and what you really want to do in order to provide usable code, this is probably in the right ballpark.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you you do do like this:

```
foreach($_SESSION['shopcart'] as $key=>$value){
    if(is_array( $value ) ){
       foreach($value => k1 => $v1){

        //do something here if array 

         echo $k1." => ".$v1."<br/>";
       }
    }else{
         //do something here if not array 
    }
}
```